# How to adjust error when generating a graph in R software

Tags: r

Could you help me solve the following problem: I'm not able to generate the graph for the `df2` dataset. As you can see for `df1` it generates normally, however if you test for `df2` it gives an error.

Thank you very much!

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)

#dataset df1
df1 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01 = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5),
       DR04 = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05 = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06 = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07 = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

#Generate graph

dmda<-"2021-07-01"

datas<-df1 %>%
  filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
  summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
  pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
  mutate(name = as.numeric(name))
colnames(datas)<-c("Days","Numbers")
attach(datas)
plot(Numbers ~ Days, ylim=c(0,20))

model <- nls(Numbers ~ b1*Days^2+b2,start = list(b1 = 47,b2 = 0))

new.data <- data.frame(Days = seq(min(Days),max(Days),len = 45))
lines(new.data$Days,predict(model,newdata = new.data))
```

[image]

```
df2 <- structure(
  list(date1 = c("2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28",
                 "2021-06-28","2021-06-28","2021-06-28"),
       date2 = c("2021-04-02","2021-04-03","2021-04-08","2021-04-09","2021-04-10","2021-07-01","2021-07-02","2021-07-03"),
       Week= c("Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Thursday","Friday","Monday"),
       DR01_DR01_PV = c(4,1,4,3,3,4,3,6), DR02_DR02_PV= c(4,2,6,7,3,2,7,4),DR03_DR03_PV= c(9,5,4,3,3,2,1,5), DR04_DR04_PV = c(5,4,3,3,6,2,1,9),DR05_DR05_PV = c(5,4,5,3,6,2,1,9),
       DR06_DR06_PV = c(2,4,3,3,5,6,7,8),DR07_DR07_PV = c(2,5,4,4,9,4,7,8)),
  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))


#Generate graph

dmda<-"2021-07-01"
   
 datas<-df2 %>%
+   filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>%
+   summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>%
+   pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", values_to = "val") %>%
+   mutate(name = as.numeric(name))
Warning message:
Problem with `mutate()` column `name`.
i `name = as.numeric(name)`.
i NAs introduced by coercion 
colnames(datas)<-c("Days","Numbers")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is just a warning message, and the warning is because the column 'name' is having characters other than digits.  We may use `parse_number` instead

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df2 %>% 
   filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>% 
   summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", 
     values_to = "val") %>%
   mutate(name = readr::parse_number(name))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
   name   val
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     4
2     2     2
3     3     2
4     4     2
5     5     2
6     6     6
7     7     4
```

i.e. after the `pivot_longer`, it returns the whole column name because the one captured is `.+` ie. one or more any character `.` refers to any character in `regex`

```
> df2 %>% 
+    filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>% 
+    summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>% 
+    pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(.+)", 
+      values_to = "val")
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  name         val
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 01_DR01_P      4
2 02_DR02_PV     2
3 03_DR03_PV     2
4 04_DR04_PV     2
5 05_DR05_PV     2
6 06_DR06_PV     6
7 07_DR07_PV     4
```

Instead, if we change the `(.+)` to `(\\d+)`, then it matches more specifically to the digits part

```
df2 %>% 
   filter(date2 == ymd(dmda)) %>% 
   summarize(across(starts_with("DR"), sum)) %>% 
   pivot_longer(everything(), names_pattern = "DR(\\d+)", 
     values_to = "val")
# A tibble: 7 x 2
  name    val
  <chr> <dbl>
1 01        4
2 02        2
3 03        2
4 04        2
5 05        2
6 06        6
7 07        4
```

Comment: Thanks for answering and for the excellent explanation!